# Creating and populating subfolders Joomla manifest XML

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, manifest, joomla-extensions

I've become fairly confused when I'm trying to create a subfolder and populate it with things in my plugin manifest XML.

If I want to create a subfolder and at the same time add files to it, how would that be done? Read comments in the code draft (all names are of course more distinct than used here).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="plugin"  version="2.5.0" group="group" method="upgrade">

    <name>Handelsbanken Finans Delbetalning</name>
    <!-- The following elements are optional and free of formatting conttraints -->
    <creationDate>July 2013</creationDate>
    <author>Emil Carlsson</author>
    <authorUrl>http://valid.url</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2013</copyright>
    <version status="BETA">0.0.1</version>
    <!-- The description is optional and defaults to the name -->
    <description>Plugin description.</description>

    <update> <!-- Runs on update; New in 1.6 -->
        <schemas>
            <schemapath type="mysql">sql/updates/mysql</schemapath>
        </schemas>
    </update>

    <!-- Site Main File Copy Section -->
    <!-- Note the folder attribute: This attribute describes the folder
        to copy FROM in the package to install therefore files copied
        in this section are copied from /site/ in the package -->
    <files folder="site">
        <filename>plgName.xml</filename>
        <filename>plgName.php</filename>
        <folder>helpers</folder>
    </files>

</extension>
```

This gives me nothing really. I can't find the folder I shouldhave been created from what I gathered from the documentation. It also doesn't specifies how I populate these folder :(. I am assuming that it is possible to more or less just package all files I want and then it will create the subfolders where I want/need them. But that it is a question of how to write the manifest file. If anyone have a good tutorial about this I would be very thankful :). I've googled until my fingers are almost at the Point of bleeding :(. I guess I could put all the files in the same folder, but I want to have some sort of structure to visualize for other developers what's part of the core of the plugin and what's not part of the plugin core.

Comment: Also, I am using joomla 2.5.

Comment: Well as a starting, you manifest file is incorrect and is for Joomla 2.5. You're using the `<install>` tags. Check out the following link for Joomla 2.5 standards: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component

Comment: Also you don't need to specify folders content, just the folder will do. And drop the language declaration, add a language folder and you will keep you language files under the plugin main folder instead of in the main /language folder.

Comment: I've transfered the installation XML to this format, but the same problem is still present. I can't get subfolders to be copied into the installation. (note: I've now updated the source snippet in the question).

Should the language folder be:

[root]

-[language]

-[site]


or:

[root]

-[site]

--[language]

Comment: Right now you have one folder you are creating, helpers. Are you saying helpers is not being created?  The examples in the core are your friends.
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/plugins/user/profile/profile.xml

Comment: Why do you have the basic files inside a folder named site? They should just go to the folder 'group that you named in the second line.

Comment: I have the site folder mostly because of the fact that the example on [this link](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component) used that. Prior I had it in the root folder with nothing more. And the example you directed me to is more or less what my previous XML file looked like. But I have separated the installation part and the params part (and that works fine). The main problem is that my subfolders isn't created and copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. In my not installation script I linked in the files for what I thought only was used by the configuration XML (a field to configurate the plugin). In this file I had the node "files" as well, in this node I'd not linked in the helpers directory. When this was done all the subdirectories was added as well. So in short - Don't forget to link in the folder in all places where you have a files-node.